# Pandas Import Fails with Conda on Python 3.7.9

Tags: python, pandas, conda

I have installed conda and created a python3.7 environment. Then I have installed `pandas` and now I'm getting the following error when I try to import `pandas`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "/me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: /me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: /me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "/me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: /me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: /me/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install `pandas`? Apparently the C extensions weren't built properly for your system. Are you using a 32- or 64-bit build of Python?

Comment: Using this `conda install pandas` as described on the pandas installation guide.

Comment: Also, are you attempting to run the code in the new environment when it is the active environment?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is a bug with `conda` and `pandas`.

Here is the ticket:
[BUG: Pandas Import is failing under Conda Python 3.7](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39802)

Using `conda-forge` fixed the issue for me.